# VBA Offsett in Python

Tags: python, vba, excel, xlwings

I would like to add the returns of a json to excel cell by cell, like

```
2003-1  2003-2  2003-3  2003-4  2003-5  2003-6  2003-7  2003-8  2003-9 ....
number  number  number  number  number  number  number  number  number ....
```

Here is my code, but as can be understood it only pastes to the first cell, I could not construct the system I wanted. Thank you in advance..

```
    from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
    import requests
    import json

    payload = {'cityId':3969, 'lbDistricts':599, 'criter':149,'startdate':'2003-01','cmd':'result','areaCode':18439}
    url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    wb = Workbook()
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    data = map(dict.values, data[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
    for row in data:



Range("A1").value = '{:10}{:10}'.format(*row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc's: "When assigning (nested) lists to a Range in Excel, it’s enough to just specify the top left cell as target address."

So you can just do (without iterating over the 2D list and assigning 1 row at a time):

```
Range("A1").value = data
```

Or if you want to transpose the list that be done with:

```
Range("A1").value = zip(*data)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do by formatting the strings, but hopefully that wasn't a part of your issue.

http://docs.xlwings.org/datastructures.html#lists

Comment: Yes solved the problem! thank you, i will handle formatting the strings